# How to generate dropdown menu in Shiny dashboard dynamically using MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a MySQL database that contains multiple tables. Now I want to create a dropdown menu in Shiny dashboard that automatically adds values based on the unique values of each column of the tables.

My code to connect to the DB is

```
    library(RMySQL)

options(mysql = list(
 "host" = "localhost",
 "port" = 3306,
 "user" = "root",
 "password" = "root"
))

databaseName <- "Apilogs"
table <- "Eventlog"


loadData <- function() {
    # Connect to the database
    db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = databaseName, host = options()$mysql$host,
      port = options()$mysql$port, user = options()$mysql$user,
      password = options()$mysql$password)
    # Construct the fetching query
    query <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM eventlog", table)
    # Submit the fetch query and disconnect
    data <- dbGetQuery(db, query)
    dbDisconnect(db)
    data
}
```

Now I have my dropdown in the sidebar

```
        selectInput("region", "Region:",
              choices = colnames("I WANT TO POPULATE THIS FROM THE DB"))
```

How can I do this.

Comment: What is the output of `loadData()`?

Comment: @shosaco no output as of now

Comment: updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = ''region", choices = yourchoices) in server side..

Comment: @Ika8 the can I pass a SQL query in choices

Comment: Something like `choices = colnames(loadData())`, but depends what your data looks like.

Comment: @shosaco Okay. thanks

Comment: @Will choices receive a list of items.. in your loadData() you should retrieve either a list or a dataframe so you can use loadData$columnNameWithChoices